# Casperjs CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector:

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am new to using Casperjs and I am trying to get this script to copy some text but it is unable to find the search button even though I have the right path. I have been able to click all buttons in the script before but it gives the error at the line:

```
    casper.wait(2000, function () {
        casper.click(x('//*[@id="SRCHBTN"]'));     <----Error here
        casper.capture('CurrentScreen.png');
    });


CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector:
```

Here is the code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');

casper.start('url');

casper.then(function () {
    this.sendKeys('user', 'user');
    this.sendKeys('pswd', 'pass');
    console.log('Entering Data');

});

casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="login"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input'), function () {
    console.log('Logging in..');
});

casper.wait(2000, function () {
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="SRCH_LINK"]/a'));
});

casper.wait(2000, function () {
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="SRCHBTN"]'));
    casper.capture('CurrentScreen.png');
});






casper.wait(4000, function () {
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="TITLE_HL$0"]'));
casper.wait(2000, function() {

    //this is pop up window section

    casper.waitForPopup(/popup\.html$/, function () {
        this.test.assertEquals(this.popups.length, 1);
    });

    // this will set the popup DOM as the main active one only for time the
    // step closure being executed
    casper.withPopup(/popup\.html$/, function () {
        this.test.assertTitle('Job Details - Google Chrome');
        var targetText = casper.fetchText('#DESCR');
        console.log(targetText);
    });

    // next step will automatically revert the current page to the initial one
    casper.then(function () {
        this.test.assertTitle('Main page title');
    });





    });
});


casper.run();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the existence of expected element depends on an asynchronous call, waiting for 2 seconds will not guarantee the call is completed. 
Instead of `wait()` you should use the `waitForSelector()` function:

```
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="SRCHBTN"]'), function () {
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="SRCHBTN"]'));
    casper.capture('CurrentScreen.png'); });
});
```

Comment: now after I put wait ForSelector I get 


TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.waitForselector')
  


Entering Data
Logging in..
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.

Comment: Try waitForSelector (with upper case S)

Comment: @mirovarga that is what I was trying but still get that error

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the xpath implementation, try css selector: casper.waitForSelector('[id="SRCHBTN"]')

Comment: If you get a timeout, either the web page is very slow (I guess you would have noticed it by testing it manually, but if that's the case, you can change the default timeout value), either the previous actions in your test script haven't triggered the mechanism in charge of producing the expected element.